# Consider the set $S = \{x : Ax = 0\}$. Show that $\dim (S) = n-r$ where $r$ is the number of Linearly Independent rows of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the set $S = \{x : A_{m \times n}x = 0\}$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $\dim (S) = n-r$ where $r$ is the number of Linearly Independent rows of $A$.

Can we directly use the rank-nullity theorem? I can not think of a linear map $T : S \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically *is* the rank-nullity theorem. Note that $S = \mathrm{ker}(T)$, where the linear map you look for is $T(x) := Ax$. $r$ is nothing else than $\mathrm{rank}(T)$ (remember that row rank equals column rank). Therefore
$$
n = \mathrm{rank}(T) +\dim\mathrm{ker}(T) = r+ \mathrm{dim}(S)
$$
according to the rank nullity theorem.

Comment: you mean $n={rank}(T) + \dim\ker(T) = r+\dim (S)$

Comment: Of course, thank you

Comment: what are you referring to?